# How would I be able to send an email through my vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am working on my semester project which is an Windows version of an e-commerce application. I want to send e-mail to my users regarding sign ups,sales, and further updates.

Comment: This is not a suitable question for this site, and is likely to be put on hold for being too broad. If you can show us what you have tried, and what difficulty you are having with it, then someone will be able to help. Only questions involving a reasonable amount of effort tend to get the best help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10s of googling gives you 10k answers..

The easiest way to send a mail with .net is by using the `System.Net.Mail` Namespace and a smtp server where you have an e-mail account like mostlikely Gmail.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Try

        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("youremailaddress@gmail.com", "yourpassword")
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        SmtpServer.Port = 465
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

        mail = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress("from@email.address")
        mail.To.Add("to@email.address")
        mail.Subject = "This is the subject"
        mail.Body = "This is the body"

        SmtpServer.Send(mail)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(Err.Number & vbNewLine & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

Hints if this doesn't work:

- check your network credentials manually
- look into your Anti-Virus eventlog, as if you use McAfee, the `System.Net.Mail` will be blocked as a spam mailworm by your own protection.
- Use the `CDOSYS` method to send a mail
- Use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` method to send a mail
- Use [Telnet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx) to test your communication with a SMTP server